# Filling the area between three points (java.awt.Point) with Graphics (java.awt.Graphics)

Tags: java, graphics, awt, java-2d

I have three points in my code and I would like to fill the area between them, or in other words draw and fill a triangle between 3 points.

I thought about simply drawing lines with a for loop (from x1 to x2) but I don't think that will be efficient, is there any other way to do this that is more efficient?

Comment: *"Thanks in advance,
Mickey Munin."*  That amounts to 2 lines of noise.  Please leave it out in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would draw a Polygon with three Points:

[`Graphics.fillPolygon(int[], int[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon%28int%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a buffered image and paint pixels one at a time.  BufferedImage is MUCH faster than using the paintcomponent of a gui object.  Use the WriteableRaster in a BufferedImage, then loop through the pixels one at a time, marking the ones that fall within your triangle.

Your algorithm looks something like:

```
equation for line 1
equation for line 2
equation for line 3
then for each point as you loop through writeableraster:  
    check if x and y are each between the three lines
```

Alternatively, you could try [this example](http://csis.pace.edu/~wolf/cs121/DrawTriangles.html) which is more of a paint approach.